# How to supply the Libnet header to Nemesis during installation?

Tags: linux, fedora, libnet

I'm trying to install Nemesis on Fedora 31, but it throws the error below.
How can I supply the Libnet header during installation?

```
root@dk:/usr/nembuild/nemesis-1.4$ ./configure
  --with-libnet-includes=/usr/nembuild/Libnet-1.0.2a/include
  --with-libnet-libraries=/usr/nembuild/Libnet-1.0.2a/lib
```

> checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
>   checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
>   checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
>   checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
>   checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
>   checking for netinet/in.h... yes
>   checking libnet.h usability... no
>   checking libnet.h presence... no
>   checking for libnet.h... no
>
> ERROR!  Libnet header not found, go get it from
>   http://www.packetfactory.net/projects/libnet/
>   or use the --with-libnet-* options, if you have it installed
>   in unusual place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this (it uses the libnet10-devel package from your Fedora 31):

- `yum install libnet10-devel`
- `sed -e 's/libnet-config/libnet10-config/g' -e 's/-lnet/-lnet10/g' -i configure`
- `./configure`
- `make`

Comment: Hello..which configuration file should i edit? Becouse when i execute the above command, i get a "sed: can't read configure: No such file or directory" thank you in advance

Comment: Well, `/usr/nembuild/nemesis-1.4/configure` (so: `yum install libnet10-devel && cd /usr/nembuild/nemesis-1.4 && sed -e 's/libnet-config/libnet10-config/g' -e 's/-lnet/-lnet10/g' -i configure && ./configure && make`)

Comment: Thank you @rsc...i appreciate your effort